# Is it possible to use variational autoencoders with Non-Gaussian data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, normal-distribution, nonparametric, autoencoders

I am dealing with two scenarios: 1) Non-Gaussian data distribution and 2) non-stationary data).

First, I am planning to use a variational autoencoder for modeling the probability distribution of the non-Gaussian data distribution in the latent space. (Note, the input of the encoder part will be the non-Gaussian data). Then, I will it to perform some classification tasks.

However, is it possible to use the variational autoencoder to deal with non-Gaussian Distribution data? (because the non-Gaussian data is not generated from a Gaussian distribution).

Second, I also want to use the variational autoencoder to deal with non-stationary data. Would it be possible to use it with non-stationary data or should I consider other ML techniques.

Comment: why non-gaussian in parenthesis? you don't mean to say it's a synonym to non-stationary, i hope. stationarity has little to do with Gaussian.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean it is a synonym. What I mean with Non-Gaussian or  non-stationary data. But, I see the confusion because of the parenthesis. Sorry for that, I will fix it.

Comment: Are you saying that the **input** data to the auto-encoder is non-gaussian, or that you wish to use a non-gaussian latent data representation in the VAE?

Comment: variational autoencoders are supposed to be used on non gaussian data. they try to transform them in a gaussian distributed latent variable, but the input data doesn't have to be gaussian.

Comment: VAE will work with non-Gaussian data. they, and most ML techniques, won't work very well with non-stationary data out of the box

Comment: If you want to use the reparametrization trick, approximate posterior (encoding latents) can have any continuous exponential family distribution. You can use whatever you want in the true posterior (loglikelihood) (edit: I mean that you are not limited in choice by the VAE itself, but the choice of distribution here should most often be based on the data, like bernoulli for binary data, gaussian for continuous in the whole real line, etc etc)

Comment: Thank you all for your follow-up comments, @Sycorax, yes I meant the input of the encoder is non-gaussian data. I edited my question to make it more clear based on the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The input\output of VAE doesn't need to be gaussian. The decoder can take the multivariate gaussian and transform it to other (possibly) non-gaussian distribution.
The latent space of VAE is gaussian because of the following properties:

- It is continuous, which is suitable for generating objects which are continuous by nature, and enables continuous interpolation.
- It can easily be represented using only 2 parameters and is thus convenient to work with and can be represented easily.
- The KL divergence between two gaussian (the second loss term in VAE) has analytical solution, and thus can be easily optimized using gradient descent
- Gaussian is a natural pick for a prior of weights for neural network (it can be proved that it is equivalent to L2 regularization)
- You can easily sample this distribution and use the reparameterization trick for the optimization.

However, gaussian is not the only choice for latent space of VAE (but for sure the most popular).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!, so is it possible to consider the VAE as a non-parametric approach since it can deal with Non-Gaussian data?. I just wanted to understand the concept for that reason I asked this question.

Comment: It depends on the exact definition of parametric model see discussion here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322049/are-deep-learning-models-parametric-or-non-parametric. But definitely they can deal with non gaussian data

Comment: Thanks @ofer-a for your explanation!